# 500 glassfish internal error while calling restful service with % sign in URL

Tags: java, rest, glassfish-3

I am getting HTTP 500 internal server error on glassfish 3.2.1 while putting % sign into URL as ledgerAccountNumber.

```
Sample url - https://domain:8181/services/generalLedgerAccountConfig/isLedgerAccountNumberInUse/200%?_=1398694030799
```

Restful service:

```
 @Path("/generalLedgerAccountConfig")
  public class ConfigGeneralLedgerAccount {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Path("isLedgerAccountNumberInUse/{ledgerAccountNumber}")
  public Response isLedgerAccountNumberInUse(@PathParam("ledgerAccountNumber") String ledgerAccountNumber) {
  ...
  }
 }
```

Any ideas why 500 http error is thrown?

Comment: Encode your URL. A `%` is URL-Encoded `%25`. What says the logfiles?

Comment: how to encode url in backbone.js? 
     var isLedgerAccountNumberInUse;
     $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: contextPath + "/services/generalLedgerAccountConfig/isLedgerAccountNumberInUse/" + value,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
    isLedgerAccountNumberInUse = response;
      return callback(!isLedgerAccountNumberInUse);
    }
  });

Comment: Dont know - I'm not using backbone. But what is the problem to replace the `%` with `%25`?

Comment: This is user entered information. {ledgerAccountNumber} part of URL. We will need to encode all the characters which user enters.

Comment: at what line the exception is thrown for your method "isLedgerAccountNumberInUse"

Answer (score 0):

% is not a valid character on its on in a URI path. It represents the start of an ASCII code for an unsafe character and anytime there is a '%' in the path it should be followed by two digits. Here it is followed by a "?".

If you want a literal % to be sent to your server you need to escape it as "%25". So your client is not properly encoding the URL. Whatever the client is, when it gets input from the user it has to properly encode that URL to get rid of illegal characters or escape legal ones.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp